# What is the correct way to handle an incorrect answer (of my own) that is undeletable before it is unaccepted?

Tags: discussion

I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27259664/391161) which looked correct at the time, but is actually very wrong. 
Unfortunately the OP accepted it prematurely and he has not yet unaccepted it, so I cannot delete it.

In the meantime, I want to achieve the following two goals.

1. Make sure nobody reads the answer and thinks it works.
2. Do something to get it removed as quickly as possible.

My first thought (after asking the OP to unaccept it) was to simply edit the answer as shown in [this history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27259664/revisions), but that seemed a little too heavy handed.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot *correct* your answer with an edit, you can:

- Edit your answer to include a warning: *Update: sorry, this answer is actually wrong, and I have requested it to be deleted*.
- Flag the post with *other* and request a moderator to delete it for you.

Optionally, leave a comment on the question so that the OP knows what happened to your answer that they accepted, once it is gone.